# In the VS 2017 Community Edition, Unable to see MVC Project option (Template is not showing)?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio Community 2017 Edition; And i am using .Net Framework 4.6.1

Under Visual C# , I am able to see following Project Options.

Crystal Report, I installed separately.

However, i am not able to see ASP.Net MVC Project Option.

Project Template is not showing ?

```
    ASP.Net Empty Web Site
    ASP.Net Web Forms Site
    ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v3)
    ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Site
    WCF Service
    ASP.Net Crystal Reports Web Site
```

I have installed all the necessary components. How do i fix this ?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking under the `> Web` tab? If that's the case, click on the `> Web` tab itself and hopefully you should see `web app for .net` & `web app for .core`

Comment: I just added the screen shot.. hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you select e.g. ASP.NET Web Application and click OK then you will be presented with various options. The MVC option is listed there.